# How to attach documents to a SOAP with XOP using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, soap, xsd, xop

I had a WSDL with MTOM and we could handle it properly: there was documentation available. This is what we ended up with. Not much testing was done on it, except that we saw it working.

```
byte[] document = ... ;
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(document, "application/octet-stream");
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(dataSource);
response.setDocument(dataHandler);
```

Now the infrastructure people changed our XSD to use XOP because it was okay for attachments in the **request**, not in the **response** which is our actual use case. So they changed our XSD and added a `xop.xsd`.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
           xmlns:tns='http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include' 
           targetNamespace='http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include' >
  <xs:element name='Include' type='tns:Include' />
  <xs:complexType name='Include' >
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace='##other' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name='href' type='xs:anyURI' use='required' />
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace='##other' />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

With this new structure, the method `setDocument` is now defined as the following: `setDocument(Include)`.

The generated `Include` class is basically the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Include", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class Include
    implements org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.ToString
{

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "href", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String href;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String value) {
        this.href = value;
    }

    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }
    // Other irrelevant methods for ToString.
}
```

My question is: **how and where do I add the document in that `Include` object?** (the document is the byte array as seen in the first code snippet)